# Breakpoint on DOM load

Tags: javascript, dom, load, break, breakpoints

I am trying to use a really old page on a website I do not have control over (so I can't edit it's resources).

The problem is that it is redirecting the page via javascript (to a 'we don't support this browser' rubbish), via setting document.location before I can set any breakpoints to then debug/workaround.

Is it possible to break as soon as the DOM loads, preferably in chrome?

Disabling javascript stops the redirect, but chrome does not allow me to view any scripts to then place break points.

Comment: Did you have the access to the page's javaScript?  Or do you detect where the redirection happens in javaScript?

Comment: I do, and it is using document.location to redirect the page.

Comment: If you do, could your `return false` before the `document.location`  to stop the redirection?

Comment: As I said I can't control the javascript, only download the js file. I need a break point to do anything!

Comment: Then do you have control over the html?

Comment: No, I do not have control over any of the resources :)

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?  I have a similar problem and am looking for a way to get a breakpoint placed in a page (that I do not control) right as it begins to execute before it redirects.

Answer (score 0):

FireBug has a "Break On Next" feature.  I'm not sure if it will work in your case, but it might be worth giving it a quick try: https://getfirebug.com/doc/breakpoints/demo.html#suspend

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Chrome likes to do something to prevent you from seeing the code when you click the stop button before the page finishes loading. It'll say something like `window.script123456738391=1;`. That makes it so you can't set a breakpoint at the right spot inside the code, especially if there's a redirect on the page before you get a chance to pause it.

What I found you can do is set a breakpoint on that first line. Next time you load the page it will break on the very first line, regardless of what it is. Then you can see all the code the page would load and set breakpoints wherever you want :)